# Is Mongoid::Document a GlobalID::Identification for ActiveJobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, activemodel, rails-activejob

According to the [ActiveJobs guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html), section 8, it says:

> This works with any class that mixes in GlobalID::Identification,
>   which by default has been mixed into Active Model classes.

`Mongoid::Document` mixes `ActiveModel::Model`, but I can't find `GlobalID::Identification` in its included_modules.

1. Where is `GlobalID::Identification` defined?
2. Can I effectively use any `Mongoid::Document` for my ActiveJobs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a mistake in the guides. `GlobalID::Identification` has been mixed in `ActiveRecord`. If you mixin `GlobalID::Identification` into your mongoid documents it will work automatically as GID requires the instance to respond to `id` (returning the uniq identifier) and the class to respond to `find` (passing an `id` will return a record).

Comment: In case it will help someone else, you "mixin" by adding `include GlobalID::Identification` to the top of your model.

Answer (score 10):

Put something like this in your initializer:

```
# config/initalizers/mongoid.rb

if defined?(Mongoid)
  # GlobalID is used by ActiveJob (among other things)
  # https://github.com/rails/globalid

  Mongoid::Document.send(:include, GlobalID::Identification)
  Mongoid::Relations::Proxy.send(:include, GlobalID::Identification)
end
```

Comment: I get `uninitialized constant Mongoid::Relations` when I try this.

Comment: For `mongoid >= 7` it's `Mongoid::Association::Proxy` instead of `Mongoid::Relations::Proxy`

Answer (score 8):

To provide more information to anyone having the same problem, you can make it work by simply adding `GlobalID::Identification` to your models.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include GlobalID::Identification
end
```

I've actually done that by reopenning `Mongoid::Document`:

```
module Mongoid::Document
  include GlobalID::Identification
end
```

However, I've got some really weird errors sometimes, with `ActiveJob` which didn't know how to serialize my models. I tried to debug it, but whenever I came into `ActiveJob` code I had:

```
pry> User.is_a? GlobalID::Identification
=> true
```

But [ActiveJob::Arguments.serialize_argument](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activejob/lib/active_job/arguments.rb#L51) didn't work as expected.

The workaround is also to reopen `Mongoid::Relations::Proxy`:

```
class Mongoid::Relations::Proxy
  include GlobalID::Identification
end
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the `SerializationError` bug?

Comment: I've already tried with a simple application but it didn't work. I'm having this problem in a complex application but I haven't found any reason for this bug to happen.
In the engine with this code, it works well, but when I use it inside a Rails app, I can see that my models have `GlobalID::Identification` but some of them fail to serialize correctly

Comment: I fought with this for a while, and what I saw was that an object pulled off a belongs_to association was not reporting as being a `GlobalID::Identification` object. My fix was to also include `GlobalID::Identification` into `Mongoid::Relations::Proxy`. I believe its related to mongoid's use of marshalable, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @c.apolzon, I'll try that soon and add it to my post if it works.

Comment: This code should be put in an initializer I guess ?

Comment: @CyrilDD I actually load it from another (private) gem which handles all ActiveJob stuff. But you can do it in an initializer also !